# Trouble uploaded multiple files and saving the paths to database

Tags: php, mysql

Ok Basically i am following this guide which is pretty straight forward but, I am at the point now where i am completely lost. I don't want to have to start all over again and I hope it's just a minor adjustment but anyhow heres the error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to     copy() function cannot be a directory in /I don't want to publicize the path name/html/add.php on line 39

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpqd62Gk' to 'thumbnails/' in /I don't want to publicize the path name/add.php on line 39
Sorry, there was a problem uploading your cover. Please check it is the appropriate size and format.
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /I don't want to publicize the path name/add.php on line 52

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpFVlGsv' to 'audio/' in /I don't want to publicize the path name/add.php on line 52
Sorry, there was a problem uploading your song. Please check it is the appropriate size and format.
```

And here is the "add.php" which is executed after submitting the form :

```
<?php 
include "db_config.php";

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$targetp = "thumbnails/"; 
$targetp = $targetp . basename( $_FILES['cover']['artist']); 

//This is our size condition 
if ($uploaded_size > 100000) 
{ 
echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
$ok=0; 
} 

//This is the directory where songs will be saved 
$targets = "audio/"; 
$targets = $targets . basename( $_FILES['song']['artist']); 

//This is our size condition 
if ($uploaded_size > 6000000) 
{ 
echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
$ok=0; 
} 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $title=$_POST['title']; 
 $artist=$_POST['artist']; 
 $cover=($_FILES['cover']['artist']); 
 $song=($_FILES['song']['artist']); 
 $today = date("Ymd"); 
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


 //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Thumbnails` VALUES ( '', '$artist - $title', '$cover', '', '$song', '$title', '$artist',  '$today', '$ip')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'], $targetp)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['cover']['artist']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
  } 
  else { 

  //Gives and error if its not 
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your cover. Please check it is the appropriate size and format."; 
   } 

   //Duplicate for song
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['song']['tmp_name'], $targets)) 
   { 

    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['song']['artist']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
    } 
    else { 

    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your song. Please check it is the appropriate size and format."; 
    } 
    ?>
```

Perhaps a step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as it has gotten to the point where it all feels like scribble on a screen but, I'd hate to start all over again.

Comment: what you get var_dump($_FILES); ? thumbnails folder exist ?

Comment: No, the thumbnails folder does exist.

Comment: Create the thumbnails folder? But, its already there?

Answer (score 1):

Try to

Change

```
basename( $_FILES['cover']['artist']);
```

To

```
basename( $_FILES['cover']['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $targetp = "/thumbnails/;

 $targets = "/audio/";
```

or specify full path name like c:/some/path/here